# Is it possible to get a list of all the words in a language via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

When you type into a text field, the browser shows you words that you have misspelled. They indicate it is misspelled but it is comparing the word to a list of words in it's language dictionary.

Can I get a list of all the words in a dictionary via JavaScript? I don't need the definitions only the words. I know it might be 100,000 entries but that is why I'd like to use the built in dictionary than pulling in an external libbrary.

Example:

```
var word = "typpo";
var language = new LanguageManager("en-US");
var wordlist = language.getWords();
var inDictionary = wordList.indexOf(word)!=0;

if (inDictionary==false) {
    Dialog.show("You misspelled this word " + word);
}
```

Comment: find a spellcheck API service

Comment: Programmatically I don't think js has access to the spell check dictionary, but you could get the same library some of the browsers use, hunspell

Comment: I have used some hunspell dictionaries in the past. I could rename the extension to js if it is in plain text (i don't know) and have a word list but that would add 500kb - 2mb to the page download.

Comment: @charlietfl The word list is for more than an occasional spell check. I would like an autocorrect list and some other features. I might use a dictionary definition service tho.